# How to get scoped variable to pass between angular bootstrap modals

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I feel like this may be a duplicate of [Angularjs UI Modal Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935476/angularjs-ui-modal-forms) but I've looked at that for like an hour and I still can't get this to work.

I'm trying to have a modal pop up where you can set the name of something, add that name to an existing hash and then save that hash to an array, but for some reason I can't get the name to bind from the html back to the modal instance, so I'm always stuck with the initial name value.

Here's a plunker I made to demonstrate the problem:
http://plnkr.co/edit/zk6eZo7Xq17tiiSOO2Cv?p=preview

Here's the code involved for your convenience if you'd rather not look at the plunker:

the html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.js">    </script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="ModalCtrl" ng-init="roll={numSides: 6}">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Save your custom roll!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        Name: <input ng-model="name" />
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</script>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="save(roll)" >Save to Common Rolls</button>
    {{roll.name}}
 </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

the js:

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var ModalCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

  $scope.name = "initial name";

  $scope.save = function (customRoll) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: SaveRollCtrl,
      resolve: {
        customRoll: function () {
      customRoll.name = $scope.name;
      $log.info('customRoll.name: ' + customRoll.name);
      return customRoll;
    }
  }
});

modalInstance.result.then(function(customRoll) {
    $log.info(customRoll);
  }, function () {
    $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
  });
  };
};

// Please note that $modalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $modal service used above.

var SaveRollCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, $log, customRoll) {
  $log.info('customRoll.name: ' + customRoll.name);
  $scope.name = customRoll.name;

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $log.info('instance name: ' + $scope.name);
    customRoll.name = $scope.name;
    $modalInstance.close(customRoll);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
};
```

Comment: Instead of adding `name` straight on `$scope` try add an object on `$scope` that has a `name` attribute....so `$scope.user.name` and make all the relevant changes in the code. Check this out http://plnkr.co/edit/Gk89M8KBtn2bfwVuS1Tv?p=preview does that do what you expect?

Comment: That works too. I eventually figured out a way to do this (see my answer below) that's fairly similar to what you suggested here. I guess it just needs to be inside a hash instead of as a string to be able to pass and bind correctly for some reason I don't quite understand.

Comment: http://thenittygritty.co/angularjs-pitfalls-using-scopes Pitfall #5 helps explain if you're interested.

Comment: Oh wow, this is incredibly useful! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after working on this another hour or so, I FINALLY figured it out. Instead of trying to have a $scope.name value, I had the html bind to roll.name which wasn't an existing value but I was able to set it inside the modal resolve and then bind it to the modalInstance without any issues at all!

Here's the updated plunker if you're curious:
http://plnkr.co/edit/zk6eZo7Xq17tiiSOO2Cv?p=preview

and here are the changes to the javaScript:

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var ModalCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

  $scope.save = function (customRoll) {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: SaveRollCtrl,
      resolve: {
        customRoll: function () {
      $log.info('customRoll.name: ' + customRoll.name);
          customRoll.name = "initial";
          return customRoll;
        }
      }
    });

modalInstance.result.then(function(customRoll) {
    $log.info(customRoll);
  }, function () {
    $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
  });
  };
};

var SaveRollCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, $log, customRoll) {
  $log.info('customRoll.name: ' + customRoll.name);
  $scope.roll = customRoll;

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $log.info('instance name: ' + $scope.roll);
    $modalInstance.close($scope.roll);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
};
```